# Are real algebraic points dense in a real affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $V\subset \mathbb R^n $ be the zero-locus of finitely many polynomials with rational coefficients. Is it true that the set of points in $V$ whose coordinates are algebraic numbers is dense in the topology induced from $\mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; this follows from the fact that the first-order theory of real-closed fields is complete.  If $x\in V$ and $B$ is a small box around $x$ whose corners have rational coordinates, then the statement "$B\cap V\neq \emptyset$" can be expressed in the first-order language of ordered fields.    Since the first-order theory of real-closed fields is complete and that statement is true over $\mathbb{R}$, it is also true over the real closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Thus we can approximate $x$ arbitrarily closely by points whose coordinates are in the real closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks. Citing Scott Aaronson, this must be one of those proofs whose concluding steps seem to call more for a gong or cymbal than a “QED” box.